# Prometheus Alerts are not triggering for some valid cases

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

**Issue : Getting alert for source="SLACK" but not for source="APPRESELLER" and few other, however they all are equally qualified and having the same expression**

Configured prometheus alert expression to raise alerts if 95% of events taking more than 5 days.

Here are my metrics, where  *'le = days'*.

```
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="1.0",} 30.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="2.0",} 30.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="3.0",} 30.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="4.0",} 32.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="5.0",} 331.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="6.0",} 5368.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="7.0",} 9972.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="8.0",} 13990.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="9.0",} 18706.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="10.0",} 21574.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="11.0",} 21574.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="12.0",} 21574.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="APPRESELLER",le="+Inf",} 127258.0
timestamp_delta_count{source="APPRESELLER",} 127258.0
timestamp_delta_sum{source="APPRESELLER",} 1.281737829166575E7
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="1.0",} 5321.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="2.0",} 5321.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="3.0",} 5321.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="4.0",} 5321.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="5.0",} 5476.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="6.0",} 6537.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="7.0",} 8428.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="8.0",} 14113.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="9.0",} 29467.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="10.0",} 29560.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="11.0",} 29560.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="12.0",} 29579.0
timestamp_delta_bucket{source="SLACK",le="+Inf",} 180453.0
timestamp_delta_count{source="SLACK",} 180453.0
timestamp_delta_sum{source="SLACK",} 1.6216387916665478E7
```

Here is the alert expression

```
- alert: HISTORICAL_POLLING_DELTA_SLA_GREATER_THAN_5DAYS
  expr: histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(increase(timestamp_delta_bucket{group="live"}[5m])) by (le,source)) > 5
  for: 6h
```

Attaching one widget to demonstrate its %.
As all of these are lower than 95% but only slack is triggering the alert.

[image]

Please comment in case any other info needed on same. Avoided flooding page by metrics for other sources however they are similar and % can easily be guessed from attached snapshot.

*Thanks in advance !!*

Comment: I'm unsure why you're using `increase` here, I suppose I would have done:

`histogram_quantile(0.95, 
  sum by(source, le) (rate(timestamp_delta_bucket{group="live"}[5m]))
)`

Comment: I recommend looking at the chart and noting if there are any breaks in the 6h window that reset the alert. And you post the chart of the `expr`?

Comment: Hi checketts, 1. how, any way to see the 6h break. 2 that expr are responsible of generating alert. 
In the widget I simply put the % calculation => value of (le=30) / value of (le= +Inf) *100